# PHP Convert multidimensional array in one dimensional array of arrays

Tags: php

I have array of 15 elements and each element contains 1000 arrays. How can I convert all this arrays in one simple dimensional array? I need to get this inner arrays and convert this in one dimensional array of arrays.

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array[0..999]
            [1] => Array[0..999]
            [2] => Array[0..999]
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array[0..999]///items are also arrays
            [1] => Array[0..999]
        )

    [2] => Array
        (

            [0] => Array[0..999]
            [1] => Array[0..999]
            [2] => Array[0..999]
        )
....
```

It needs to look like this:

```
 Array(
[0] => Array
    [0]=>value
    [1]=>value
    [2]=>value

[1] => Array
    [0]=>value
    [1]=>value
    [2]=>value
)
```

Comment: please provide a small sample of the array

Comment: yeah i pushed enter button too soon. give me a minute

Comment: $flatArray = array_merge($multiArray); ???

Comment: what should `value` be? what do the innermost arrays look like? the ones from 0 to 999?

Comment: this is values of this[0...999 arrays]. the result array should contain only inner arrays from previous parent array.

Comment: This is not a clear [mcve].  This question is Unclear and will not make a good signpost for the canonical question of how to flatten arrays with PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_merge()` will merge multiple arrays, but you have an unspecified number in the main array.  So use the array as the parameters for `call_user_func_array()` with `array_merge()` as the callback:

```
$result = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array);
```

As of PHP 5.6 use argument unpacking:

```
$result = array_merge(...$array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty 'main' array and merge the 15 arrays into it

```
$main_array = [];

foreach($big_array as $value)
{
    $main_array = array_merge($main_array,$value);
}
```

e.g:

```
$main_array = [];
foreach([[1],[2],[3,4,5,6,7]] as $value)
{
    $main_array = array_merge($main_array,$value);
}
print_r($main_array);

//output
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 7
)
```

Answer (score 0):

A recursive function, one that calls itself, could do the trick, e.g.

```
<?php

$currentArray = [*your multi-dim array*];
$targetArray = [];

$level = 0;

$targetArray = flattenArray($currentArray, $targetArray, $level);

function flattenArray($currentArray, $targetArray, $level){
  foreach($currentArray as $value){
    if(is_array($value) AND $level < 1){
      $targetArray = flattenArray($value, $targetArray, $level + 1);
    }else{
      $targetArray[] = array(print_r($value, TRUE));
    }
  }
  return $targetArray;
}

?>
```